# WCF: How to set AnnouncementService only receive localhost on/off line message

Tags: wcf, discovery

i create a wcf-lib, i just want a interprocess communication.
when i open a app, who is use the lib, will announce each other.
i use UdpAnnouncementEndpoint, it work.
but it will receive the announcement from Intranet.
what can i do ?

and i create endpoint by code like this:

```
    private void ActionInitClientService()
    {
        // Create ClientSelt ServiceHost
        _clientServiceHost = new ServiceHost(_clientInstance);
        _clientServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint((typeof (IClientService)), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), Info.Address);

        // Make the client discoverable via Udp
        // and Broadcast itself to Online announcement
        _clientServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
        var discoveryBehavior = new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior();
        discoveryBehavior.AnnouncementEndpoints.Add(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());
        _clientServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(discoveryBehavior);

        _clientServiceHost.Opened += OnOpenedClientServiceHost;
        _clientServiceHost.Closed += OnClosedClientServiceHost;
    }
```

and add a AnnouncementsListener in the host:

```
    private void ActionInitAnnouncementsListener()
    {
        var announcementService = new AnnouncementService();
        announcementService.OnlineAnnouncementReceived += OnOnlineAnnouncementReceived;
        announcementService.OfflineAnnouncementReceived += OnOfflineAnnouncementReceived;

        _announcementsListener = new ServiceHost(announcementService);
        _announcementsListener.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize, I was looking at the wrong part of your code. You are not using the named pipes in order to make your client discoverable.

Here it is how you can get the IP address of the incoming message (I assume that based on that IP address you can deduce using some code logic if your message comes from your intranet or not).

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpointProperty = messageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
```

The above code was founnd on the following link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f14520be-d77d-401f-b339-9c58585857f7/

You cana also find more in depth details on http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/20/observableservicehost-an-instancecontext-creation-aware-wcf-servicehost/.

Comment: Thank you Mihai,the filter work.and i also want to know if there is a property for the announcement scope?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand correctly the meaning of "announcement scope". Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: I might be wrong but... try to apply discovery behavior to all your service endpoints not only to the announcement endpoint. That should provide you a scope for your endpoints if that is what you are searching for. Also check the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335779.aspx

Comment: no, your first answer is right.
eg. i run my app in PC.A, and i dont want to receive PC.B's announcement .

and i have readed the msdn link.
it say :The client would receive all notifications of all services in the  intranet, regardless of contract type or, for that matter, applications or scopes. The client must filter out the relevant announcements.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not. You are using a NetNamedPipeBinding which is valid only if both client and service run on same machine. By its definitions NetNamePipeBinding provides a secure and reliable binding that is optimized for on-machine communication.

Comment: yes,i using a NetNamedPipeBinding, and it work well.but my worry is that AnnouncementService brought the unnecessary message.i have to determine whether the online message from the localhost or from another pc in the LAN.